# Error trying ethzasl_sensor_fusion tutorials

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am learning the ethzasl_sensor_fusion [tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ethzasl_sensor_fusion/Tutorials/getting_started). I have no problem in setting up the package and playing the bag files. But after about 2 seconds I get error messages as following:

```
=== ERROR === update: NAN at index 0
=== ERROR === prediction p: NAN at index 0
...
```

Anybody knows how to solve this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/110471/error-trying-ethzasl_sensor_fusion-tutorials/) by [ZiyangLI](https://answers.ros.org/users/3542/ziyangli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2013-12-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I too had the same issue, but re-running the steps solved the issue.
Sometimes when I initially played the dataset for about 2 sec then I had the same issue.

Specifically, after starting the bag file using this command `rosbag play dataset.bag --pause -s 25`

play the dataset for about 1 sec and again pause it by pressing spacebar. Then initialize the filter using dynamic reconfigure gui and then play it. Then resume the dataset by pressing the spacebar and this should not give the NAN error.

---

Originally posted by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) with karma: 1935 on 2014-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2